# Excel making a conditional rank?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to rank a set of scores based off of a another number attached to that score. Essentially I have an average score and I only want that average score to be included in the rank if the total number of people (count) in that average score is above 100, if not then I don't want it ranked.

[image: Help]

Comment: Hi just added the chart I'm working on, I want it to give me the ranks of the means but it wouldn't include the ranks of the 2 rows that are less than 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a FILTER function in a range somewhere then refer to that:

[image]

Formula in cell I4:

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$16,$B$2:$B$16>=$J$1)
```

Formula in column C:

```
=IFERROR(RANK.EQ(A2,$I$4#),"")
```

It would be nice to put the FILTER inside the RANK.EQ function but that doesn't appear to work.